# OpenCV VideoCapture::set iOS doesn't work

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, video

So I have written some OpenCV code on MacOS in C++ for skipping forwards and backwards inside a video doing some processing. It works correctly on MacOS, but when I tried porting the code to iOS it fails to work.

Specifically these API calls to OpenCV do not work on iOS. They do not return the correct values nor do they perform the correct operations, but they work as expected on MacOS.

`cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);//Getting the FPS doesn't return the correct value.
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO, 1);//Set relative video position doesn't work.
cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC);//Getting the duration doesn't return the correct value.
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, video_time); //Setting video timestamp doesn't work.`

Alternatively I tried replacing some of the calls using AVFoundation but the call to `cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, video_time);` Still doesn't work.

I am kind of at a loss here on what to do. Is it possible to do forward and backward time skipping using AVFoundation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is it *is* broken:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/5c13ffb73edef4d105fbafc1bff0bff3560eedb2/modules/videoio/src/cap_avfoundation.mm

The relevant code is all commented out, with it just returning true by default. See lines 1054-1101 for this.

Regarding scrubbing your video (skipping back & forward), it is possible, just look into `AVPlayer`.

Comment: Ahh okay that is unfortunate. Thank you for the answer I will go down the AVPlayer route.

Comment: Note that grab also doesn't work. I founf this post when set wasn't working for me, so I thought I would quickly iterate through frames with grab(), but it is also broken.